# Cases in salesforce

Tags: case, case-object

What is the best categorization of cases for standard salesforce object. Our users file case in salesforce but we always have vague inquiries and we end up reaching back to customer fetching more information. I am trying to come up with one page layout where user can put all the information related to case. Would someone share a screenshot of their case wizard?

I am really looking for a slick layout which only takes required information towards a case via dependent fields.

For example, if user has to merge two accounts, all he has to provide is master and duplicate account via lookup field.

Comment: how you are capturing case information from Customer?

Comment: Santanu,
This is for internal salesforce users. They click on case Tab and fill out the form.

Comment: do they fill it on behalf of a customer, or its internal cases?

Comment: @nomad, is that any of the answers solve your purpose?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. I came up with my own layout based on minimal items which I would need to get necessary information and it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is truely as design specific requirement.

There are couple ways you can present the case page so that they can enter valid information.

1. Based on request type you can define recordtype and define the Support process.
2. Based on record type you should define picklist values so that you will select proper values.
3. Based on the input, you should provide validation rule so that bad data can be restricted.
4. For crucial field input you can provide content sensitive help, so that customer can refer during entering the information.
5. You can expose knowledge article (if possible) to guide the customer.